# How to write swagger API that accepts XML in request body

Tags: java, xml, code-generation, swagger

We are using Swagger to write our REST API. We have a POST service which should accept an XML file in the request body.
This is our request definition:

```
  /services/invoke:
    post:
      tags:
        - invoke
      summary: A request invocation
      operationId: invokeUsingPOST
      consumes:
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - application/xml
      parameters:
        - name: User-Token
          in: header
          description: The user token
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: request
          description: invoke request XML
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: string
        '400':
          description: Bad Operation
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '404':
          description: Forbidden
```

However, when we generate a Java client code using swagger-codegen, the generated method looks like:

```
public String invokeUsingPOST (String userToken, Request request)
```

And the Request class is generated as:

```
@ApiModel(description = "")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2015-11-25T18:45:31.524+02:00")
public class Request   {
  @Override
  public String toString()  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Request {\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

How do I use it to send my XML? Do I have to derive from it and override the toString() method, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug, which was addressed about 2 hours ago. Please pull the latest from [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and the parameter `request` in the Java API client should be a string instead of model.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a reference to the issue, or the fix?
Anyway, this helps but doesn't fix the problem, as the call fails because it calls serialize() which expect its payload to be JSON, and throws an exception if not. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/Java/ApiClient.mustache#L386

Comment: I get this exception:
Caused by: io.swagger.client.ApiException: can not serialize object into Content-Type: application/xml
        at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.serialize(ApiClient.java:386)
        at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.getAPIResponse(ApiClient.java:493)
        at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:540)

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new and we'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround for me is to add another else if into serialize method for checking if content type is "application/xml"

```
} else if (contentType.equals("application/xml")) {
            SerializerUtils s = new SerializerUtils();
            return s.serializeRequestBody(contentType, obj);
}
```

and SerializerUtils have these 2 methods

```
public class SerializerUtils {

public Marshaller registerSerializer(Class<?> modelClass) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(modelClass);

    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    return jaxbMarshaller;
}

public RequestBody serializeRequestBody(String contentType, Object obj) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        registerSerializer(obj.getClass()).marshal(obj, sw);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), sw.toString());
}
```

This Works for me and i hope it helps

Comment: and annotate your model Classes with @XmlRootElement